# Select time from base as UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, laravel-5

I have in base field with type `datetime`, it's `time` field. I want to get all elements from base and get additional `timeu` field - it's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)`. I try to do this by add `->select('*','UNIXTIMESTAMP(time) AS timeu')` but Laravel gives me error. I need it to use in `->keyBy()`. I have next error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)' in 'field list' (SQL: select *, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)` as `timeu` from `values` where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) <= 1429135199 and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) >= 1428444000 order by `id` asc)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel needs to know that `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as timeu` is a RAW SQL expression and not a column name:

```
->select('*', \DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS timeu'))
```

Or alternatively:

```
->selectRaw('*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS timeu')
```

Comment: what is the full className for 'DB' in laravel 5.2, thanks

Comment: @dencey The DB facade is located at `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` but you can just use its alias and import `use DB;`